# how to use jit on a numerical simulation

Tags: python, physics, jit

I'm trying to write a physical simulation using python which requires a lot of simple math computation. I believed that numba's jit will help me run it faster, the code is mainly calculations and I'm not sure what's wrong. I  tried putting @jit over each function I tried to specify @jit(nopython=True) and still its very slow.

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
from numba import jit

GRID = np.random.choice((-1, 1), (32, 32))


J = 1
UB = 1
BETA = 1


@jit
def energy_i_now(i, j, grid):
    E = -(UB * grid[i, j] +
          J * grid[i, j] * (grid[(i + 1) % 32, j] + grid[(i - 1) % 32, j]
                            + grid[i, (j + 1) % 32] + grid[i, (j - 1) % 32]))
    return E


@jit
def E_00(i, j, grid):
    for i in range(32):
        for j in range(32):
            E = -0.5 * (UB * grid[i, j] +
                        J * grid[i, j] * (grid[(i + 1) % 32, j] + grid[(i - 1) % 32, j]
                                          + grid[i, (j + 1) % 32] + grid[i, (j - 1) % 32]))
    return E - energy_i_now(i, j, grid)


@jit
def iterate(grid):
    E_tot = E_00(0, 0, grid) + energy_i_now(0, 0, grid)
    for i in range(32):
        for j in range(32):
            e_i_now = energy_i_now(i, j, grid)
            p_flip = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-2 * BETA * e_i_now))
            rand = np.random.random()
            if rand <= p_flip:
                grid[i, j] = grid[i, j] * -1
                E_tot -= 2 * e_i_now
    return grid


s = time()
for i in range(10):
    iterate(GRID)
print(time() - s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like JIT is being used, the slowness is because compilation time is included into benchmarked time in your code.

If attempt to pre-compile the functions first and only then do benchmarking, it'll be much faster:

```
dummy_grid = np.random.choice((-1, 1), (2, 2))
energy_i_now(0, 0, dummy_grid) #poor man's pre-compilation, call each function at least once in advance
E_00(0, 0, dummy_grid)
iterate(dummy_grid)

s = time()
for i in range(10):
    iterate(GRID)
print(time() - s)
```

Also as per [Numba doc](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#cache), there is `cache` compilation option:

> To avoid compilation times each time you invoke a Python program, you can instruct Numba to write the result of function compilation into a file-based cache. This is done by passing cache=True:
> `@jit(cache=True)`

Comment: Thank you very much!!  I understood  that it's kind of common practice to run your code  with  writing the line
if __name__ == "__main__":??
and then putting all the functions inside . is this a better pre-compilation ?

Comment: @TomerGigi , honestly i don't know. I would try to go with `@jit(cache=True)` decorator for each method.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
from numba import jit

GRID = np.random.choice((-1, 1), (32, 32))


J = 1
UB = 1
BETA = 1


@jit
def energy_i_now(i, j, grid):
    E = -(UB * grid[i, j] +
          J * grid[i, j] * (grid[(i + 1) % 32, j] + grid[(i - 1) % 32, j]
                            + grid[i, (j + 1) % 32] + grid[i, (j - 1) % 32]))
    return E


@jit
def E_00(i, j, grid):
    for i in range(32):
        for j in range(32):
            E = -0.5 * (UB * grid[i, j] +
                        J * grid[i, j] * (grid[(i + 1) % 32, j] + grid[(i - 1) % 32, j]
                                          + grid[i, (j + 1) % 32] + grid[i, (j - 1) % 32]))
    return E - energy_i_now(i, j, grid)


@jit
def iterate(grid):
    E_tot = E_00(0, 0, grid) + energy_i_now(0, 0, grid)
    for i in range(32):
        for j in range(32):
            e_i_now = energy_i_now(i, j, grid)
            p_flip = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-2 * BETA * e_i_now))
            rand = np.random.random()
            if rand <= p_flip:
                grid[i, j] = grid[i, j] * -1
                E_tot -= 2 * e_i_now
    return grid

new = np.random.choice((-1, 1), (2, 2))
energy_i_now(0, 0, new)
E_00(0, 0, new)
iterate(new)


s = time()
for i in range(10):
    iterate(GRID)
print(time() - s)
```

Comment: @Renat If my answer, or that of other users, was the solution to your question, please accept the answer as Stackoverflow Help Center rules, thank you